# Vimrc tries to execute command defined on leader

Tags: key-bindings, vimrc, command-line

I'm trying to have something like this in my .vimrc:

```
nnoremap <leader>has :w | ! reset; runhaskell % <cr>
```

How ever, now it prompts an error when loading .vimrc and tells me:

```
:! reset; runhaskell r_packages.markdown 
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/bin/bash: -c: line 0: ` reset; runhaskell r_packages.markdown '
```

How should I write my key mapping so as the bash command is executed only on my leader key mapping ? And not when vim starts up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vim interprets the pipe character as a command termination and tries to execute what's afterwards as if it was an Ex command which was not part of the `nnoremap` mapping.
To prevent this, you have to escape the pipe or replace it with the corresponding keycode `<bar>`:

```
nnoremap <leader>has :w <bar> ! reset; runhaskell % <cr>
```