# How to run additional command in nnoremap?

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

I have the following lines in my `.vimrc`:

```
nnoremap <nowait><silent> ¡ :colorscheme tokyonight<CR>
nnoremap <nowait><silent> ™ :colorscheme tone<CR>
nnoremap <nowait><silent> £ :colorscheme darktooth<CR>
nnoremap <nowait><silent> ¢ :colorscheme soft-morning<CR>
nnoremap <nowait><silent> ∞ :colorscheme gruvbox<CR>
nnoremap <nowait><silent> § :colorscheme shirotelin<CR>
hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
hi! NonText ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=NONE ctermfg=NONE
```

How should I do to make all of these `nnoremap` mappings to execute the two lines

```
hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
hi! NonText ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=NONE ctermfg=NONE
```

at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several ways to do it:

- You can use `<bar>` which is the key code for `|` to be used in a mapping ([**Do not use `|` directly in your mapping**](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/7244/1841)):

  ```
  nnoremap <leader>a :echo "fizz" <bar> echo "buzz"<CR>
  ```

  This is the equivalent of running `:echo "fizz" | echo "buzz"` in the command line.
- You can also map it has two normal mode commands:

  ```
  nnoremap <leader>a :echo "fizz"<CR>:echo "buzz"<CR>
  ```

  Which is the equivalent of running `:echo "fizz"` then `:echo "buzz"`
- If things get more complicated I'd go with a function which makes it easier to group your commands and add logic if needed.

  ```
  function! MyFunction()
      colorscheme tokyonight
      hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
  endfunction

  nnoremap <leader>a :call MyFunction()<CR>
  ```
- And to keep it more concise you could even use a user defined command:

  ```
  function! MyFunction()
      colorscheme tokyonight
      hi Normal ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE
  endfunction

  command! ColorschemeCommand call MyFunction

  nnoremap <leader>a :ColorschemeCommand<CR>
  ```

You can even lookup [`:h :command-nargs`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/map.txt.html#%3Acommand-nargs) to add arguments to your commands so that you can reuse the same command with different arguments for all of your mappings.

---

**Edit**

As Ben pointed out in the comments, you particular use case could also benefit from the autocommand event [`:h ColorScheme`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#ColorScheme). If you are not familiar with autocommands they are a built-in way to run commands after a trigger (here after loading a colorscheme). See [`:h autocmd`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd) for more details.

Comment: or autocmd ColorScheme

Comment: Indeed in this particular case that also works.

Comment: Thank you so much! I take the third approach while I have to write `function!` instead or I will get error. Is the reason because I need to call it many times?

Comment: @job_start I edited my answer to add the `!`: This is often needed `!` when you create a function. This allows to redefine a function with the same name which can happen when you source your vimrc several time. See [`:h E122`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#E122)

Comment: @job_start (somewhat) recent vim versions have made an exception so that ! is not necessary when the same script that defines the function overwrites it (so that re-sourcing works). So it *shouldn’t* be necessary… obviously, whatever works for you is preferable.